# Why the inner array values are not getting sorted in ascending order of UNIX times tamp values in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've an multi-dimensional array titled `$events` as follows :

```
print_r($events);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065590 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:53:10 GMT
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 237
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065259 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:47:39 GMT
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => TestGroupShweta
                    [event_id] => 238
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065491 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:51:31 GMT
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 252
                    [time_stamp] => 1438063373 //Tue, 28 Jul 2015 06:02:53 GMT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 244
                    [time_stamp] => 1437475382 //Tue, 21 Jul 2015 10:43:02 GMT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => The Namesake
                    [event_id] => 243
                    [time_stamp] => 1437468870 //Tue, 21 Jul 2015 08:54:30 GMT
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 242
                    [time_stamp] => 1437391684 //Mon, 20 Jul 2015 11:28:04 GMT
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 201
                    [time_stamp] => 1428315119 //Mon, 06 Apr 2015 10:11:59 GMT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 240
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114920 //Fri, 17 Jul 2015 06:35:20 GMT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 241
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114922 // Fri, 17 Jul 2015 06:35:22 GMT
                )   

        )

)
```

If you observe closely the elements with index `[3]` and `[5]` contain three inner array elements. I want to sort these three array elements within themselves in ascending order of UNIX time stamp value present in a key `time_stamp` of respective inner array.

This sorting operation should be performed only when there are more than one inner array elements are present. In above array it should be performed only in case of `[3]` and `[5]`, not for other elements.

The inner array index should also be changed (i.e. from 0,1,2,3,....so on).

After performing the sorting operation, the desired sorted array should be exactly as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065590 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:53:10 GMT
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 237
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065259 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:47:39 GMT
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => TestGroupShweta
                    [event_id] => 238
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065491 //Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:51:31 GMT
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (

       [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => The Namesake
                    [event_id] => 243
                    [time_stamp] => 1437468870 //Tue, 21 Jul 2015 08:54:30 GMT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 244
                    [time_stamp] => 1437475382 //Tue, 21 Jul 2015 10:43:02 GMT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 252
                    [time_stamp] => 1438063373 //Tue, 28 Jul 2015 06:02:53 GMT
                )
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 242
                    [time_stamp] => 1437391684 //Mon, 20 Jul 2015 11:28:04 GMT
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 201
                    [time_stamp] => 1428315119 //Mon, 06 Apr 2015 10:11:59 GMT
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 240
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114920 //Fri, 17 Jul 2015 06:35:20 GMT
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 241
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114922 // Fri, 17 Jul 2015 06:35:22 GMT
                )

        )

)
```

For achieving this I tried below code but it didn't work out, it didn't return me the above desired array. I'm not understanding where I'm making the mistake. Please correct my mistake in code.

```
foreach($events as $event) {
  if(sizeof($event) > 1) { 
    foreach($event as &$allFeed) { 
      usort($allFeed,function($a,$b) { 
        return $a['time_stamp'] - $b['time_stamp']; 
      }); 
    }    
  }
}
```

This should be done in efficient and reliable way.

The array I got after trying following code is as below:

```
uasort($events,function($a,$b){
          return strtotime($b[0]['time_stamp'])-strtotime($a[0]['time_stamp']);
        });
        print_r($events);


Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 201
                    [time_stamp] => 1428315119
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 240
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114920
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 241
                    [time_stamp] => 1437114922
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 252
                    [time_stamp] => 1438063373
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 244
                    [time_stamp] => 1437475382
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 0
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => The Namesake
                    [event_id] => 243
                    [time_stamp] => 1437468870
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 0
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => TestGroupShweta
                    [event_id] => 238
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065491
                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => Student Organisation
                    [event_id] => 239
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065590
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [is_liked] => 
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 237
                    [time_stamp] => 1437065259
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [is_liked] => 3397
                    [group_name] => 
                    [event_id] => 242
                    [time_stamp] => 1437391684
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($events as &$event) {
  if(count($event) > 1) { 
      usort($event,function($a,$b) { 
        return $a['time_stamp'] - $b['time_stamp']; 
      }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Good rule: __not tested = not posted__ (even if in the end the code is correct)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked me absolutely perfect. Accept your answer and upvoted it too. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @AlmaDo That's a terrible rule. I can't spot the problem because I cannot test it?